# Styling the html input to have round border

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a input box which using the x button to clear the filed.  But with adding this addition attribute to the input box the border of the input has two styles now.

In the below image the input box right border is round where as left border is straight. How I can make the border style round for both side?

[image]

code:

```
<div class="input-group">
<div class="btn-group has-feedback has-clear">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    <span id="searchclear3"
       class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle form-control-feedback form-control-clear input-group-text"
       style="pointer-events:auto; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;"
       onclick="$(this).prev('input').val('');return false;">
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

You can use the simplest css

```
input {
  border-radius: 50px; /*If it doesn't work add !important*/
}
```

Or a js code

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.style.borderRadius = '50px';
```

Or you can use a bootstrap class that is already preset (I see you are using bootstrap 4)

```
form-control-rounded
```

In this way:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-rounded" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS property `border-radius` to style it.

It has four values for each side, however, if only one value is passed, it will set it to the entire border.

Therefore, the CSS should look similar to this:

```
#form-control {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```